copy file structure including files from one storage to another incrementally using pyspark
I have a storage account dexflex and two containers source and destination.
Source container has directory and files as below:
results  
    search
        03
            Module19111.json
            Module19126.json
        04
            Module11291.json
            Module19222.json
    product
        03
            Module18867.json
            Module182625.json
        04
            Module122251.json
            Module192287.json

i am trying to copy the data incrementally from source to destination container by using the below code snippet
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


# Set up the source and destination storage account configurations
source_account_name = "dev-stor"
source_container_name = "results"
destination_account_name = "dev-stor"
destination_container_name = "results"

# Set up the source and destination paths
source_path = f"abfss://{source_container_name}@{source_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{search,product}/"
destination_path = f"abfss://{destination_container_name}@{destination_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/copy-data-2024"

# Set up the date range for incremental copy
start_date = datetime(2024, 3, 1)
end_date = datetime(2999, 12, 12)

dbutils.fs.cp(source_path, destination_path, recurse=True)

the above code is a full copy however i am more of looking towards incremental copy i.e in the next run only the new files be copied.
PS. directory hierarchy is to be the same.
I also tried autoloader but was unable to main the same hierarchical directory structure.
can i get some expert advice please

Using Azure Data Factory copy activity, you can incrementally copy files from the source to the destination. There, you will find an option for copy behavior, allowing you to choose incremental copying based on the file's last modified date and time.
For more information, refer to this documentation.
If you don't want to use Azure Data Factory and are restricted to using Databricks, you'll need to create a view that holds the timestamp when you run the copy script. When you run it again, it will copy files that were modified or added after the script was last run.
Use the following code:
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import datetime

start_date = int(datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 1).timestamp()) * 1000
data = [(start_date,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["lastmodifiedcopy"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("CPY_TBL")

Use the following code for incremental loading:
def list_files_recursively(folder_path):
    file_paths = []
    contents = dbutils.fs.ls(folder_path)
    for item in contents:
        if item.isDir():
            file_paths.extend(list_files_recursively(item.path))
        else:
            file_paths.append(item)
    return file_paths

def incremental_copy(source_path, destination_path, last_copied_time):
    files = list_files_recursively(source_path)
    print(f"Last copied time: {datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_copied_time / 1000).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')}")
    for file in files:
        if file.modificationTime >= last_copied_time:
            destination_file_path = destination_path + file.path.replace(source_path, '')
            print(destination_file_path)
            dbutils.fs.cp(file.path, destination_file_path)

    current_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) * 1000
    data = [(current_time,)]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["lastmodifiedcopy"])
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("CPY_TBL")

After copying files, update the temporary view to the current time, which will be used again for future file copying.
Call the function like this:
last_copied_time = spark.sql("select * from CPY_TBL").collect()[0][0]
incremental_copy(source_path, destination_path, last_copied_time)

Output:
1st run

2nd run after uploading some data.


i tried the code and it works perfect. however its only as long as i dont re run the first query from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import datetime
start_date = int(datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 1).timestamp()) * 1000
data = [(start_date,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["lastmodifiedcopy"])
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("CPY_TBL"). Once the code is  re execute then all the files are copied again from the start. that is a full copy happening again. could you please share how can we avoid that

Why  you re run the first query. Once view is created you no need create again it get updated for every increment copy.
